# How can I prove the monotonicity of "volume"?

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to prove the following statement:

If $A\subset B\subset \Bbb R^n$, then $$\int_{A} dx_{1}dx_{2}...dx_{n} \leq \int_{B} dx_{1}dx_{2}...dx_{n}
$$

With $\int$ representing the Lebesgue integral (or Riemann integral, I don't know if this matters).

At first glance this seems very true, but I think the proof will likely be very nontrivial. This comes from a question about Lebesgue measure and I was trying to show that if a big closed cube contains some almost disjoint small cubes, then the sum of their volume(being defined as the product of lengths of sides) will always be smaller or equal to that of the big cube.

Comment: $Vol(A) \leq Vol(A) + Vol(B\setminus A)  = Vol(B)$ since the volume (or the integrant in the notation you have) is nonnegative. The last equality is true because the two sets are disjoint.

Comment: @Dosidis Thanks for the reply! I think you are right about the integral. Bu there is a slight hiccup for the cubes: if we have many cubes, $Vol(B-A)$ is not defined. I guess that is where I stuck.

Comment: @Dosidis In case you are interested, it is Lemma 2.29 on page 20 of this file. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for an answer in the setting of the Riemann or the Lebesgue integral. Since you have seen the Lebesgue integral, we start with a $\sigma$-[algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra), which is closed under complementation and intersections. So if $A\subset B$ are in the $\sigma$-algebra, $B\setminus A = B\cap A^c$ is always measurable and its volume is defined.

Comment: @Dosidis I guess I am not very clear about the background. What I wanted to show is the translation invariance of outer measure, whose theory of course can be independent from that of Lebesgue measure. But in an approach where nothing about measurability is defined yet, can I still do it?

Comment: The lemma you are referencing is quite different to the question here. Your question as stated can be answered in the setting of these notes exactly as in my comment. If you are curious about the proof of that lemma you can open a different question. As for the question in your latest comment, you'll have to follow a book or a set of notes for that, it's too big for a question on SE.

Comment: @Dosidis I guess you are right that the question as stated is not very interesting. Thanks for the answer though! I will brainstorm more about that lemma.